Connection between sites and bands
I am studying semiconductors modelled by quasi-free, spinless electrons in a one-dimensional potential (linear electron chain) where the hamiltonian is given by
$$
\begin{equation*}
H=\sum_{\# k} \mathbf{c}_{k}^{\dagger} \cdot \mathbf{H}(k) \cdot \mathbf{c}_{k} \tag{2}
\end{equation*},
$$
where $\mathbf{c}_{k}^{\dagger}=\left(c_{k}^{\dagger}, c_{k+\pi}^{\dagger}\right)$. The hash # indicates, that the sum is to be taken over the reduced Brillouin zone, i.e. here $k \in(-\pi / 2, \pi / 2]$.
This can be written in a form that that brings out the meaning more clearly:
$$
\begin{equation*}
H=-t \sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(c_{j}^{\dagger} c_{j+1}+c_{j+1}^{\dagger} c_{j}\right)+v \sum_{j=1}^{N}(-1)^{j} n_{j}=\sum_{\# k}\left(-E_{k} a_{k}^{\dagger} a_{k}+E_{k} b_{k}^{\dagger} b_{k}\right) \tag{4}
\end{equation*},
$$
where the number operator is $n_{j}=c_{j}^{\dagger} c_{j}$ and the dispersion $E_{k}=\sqrt{4 t^{2} \cos ^{2} k+v^{2}}$. $a_k$ and $b_k$ are defined as
$$
\binom{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=\mathbf{U} \cdot\binom{c_{k}}{c_{k+\pi}}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-u_{k} & v_{k}  \tag{7}\\
v_{k}^{*} & u_{k}^{*}
\end{array}\right) \cdot\binom{c_{k}}{c_{k+\pi}}
$$
Excitons are introduced by additionally introducing an interaction between the electrons and holes. This contribution includes short-range interactions between nearest neighbour sites:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\hat{U}=u \sum_{j} n_{j} n_{j+1} \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
$$
At the edge of the Brillouin zone, $a_k$ and $b_k$ can be approximated as
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{k} & \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(-c_{k}+c_{k+\pi}\right) \\
b_{k} & \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{k}+c_{k+\pi}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
The number operators for even and odd sites, respectively, are then given by
$$
n_{2 j}=\frac{2}{N} \sum_{\# k, q} \mathrm{e}^{-i(k-q) 2 j} b_{k}^{\dagger} b_{q}
$$
$$
n_{2 j \pm 1}=\frac{2}{N} \sum_{\# k, q} \mathrm{e}^{-i(k-q)(2 j \pm 1)} a_{k}^{\dagger} a_{q}
$$
As far as I understand, $b^{\dagger}_k$ ($b_k$) creates (annihilates) an electron and $a^{\dagger}_k$ ($a_k$) has the same meaning for holes. But what I am confused about is why can I associate $b_{k}^{\dagger} b_{q}$ with the even sites and $a_{k}^{\dagger} a_{q}$ with the odd sites. So what is the connection between sites and conduction/valence bands? I understand that when an electron hops from site $n$ to site $n+1$, an electron is created at site $n+1$ and a hole remains at site $n$. But why can I generally connect the even sites to electrons and the odd ones to holes?
